# Python lxml HTML xpath query code not working

Tags: python, parsing, xpath, lxml

I am trying to scrape a page using the code below. When I run the code I get an error on the first assignment to the titles variable. The error is: AttributeError: 'NonType' object has no attribute 'split'.

If I simply replace the assignment with print(tag.text) it works as expected. Also the second assignment to the commmands variable works as expected. Why is the first assignment generating the error?

Code:

```
import requests
import lxml.html as LH

s = requests.Session()
r = s.get('http://www.rebootuser.com/?page_id=1721')

root = LH.fromstring(r.text)
def getTags():
    commands = []
    titles = []

    for tag in root.xpath('//*/tr/td[@width="54%"]/span'):
        titles += tag.text.split(',')

    for tag in root.xpath('//*/td/span/code'):
        commands += tag.text.split(',')

    zipped = zip(titles, commands)

    for item in zipped:
        print item
getTags()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the document, some tags that match xpath `//*/tr/td[@width="54%"]/span` contain `b` tag as child instead of text.

Accessing text attribute of such tag return `None`.

```
>>> None.split(',')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Use [`text_content` method](http://lxml.de/3.0/api/lxml.html.HtmlMixin-class.html) instead of `text` attribute to correctly get text content for such tag (and its children):

```
for tag in root.xpath('/tr/td[@width="54%"]/span'):
    #titles += tag.text.split(',')
    titles += tag.text_content().split(',')
```